# Mock not working on module function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest, python-mock

I have written the function `send_formatted_email` which formats email subject and message then calls the `send_email` function in a separate module.

Now I have to test that `send_formatted_email` is calling `send_email` with the expected arguments. For this purpose I am trying to mock `send_email` using `patch`, but it is not getting mocked.

test.py

```
@patch('app.util.send_email')
def test_send_formatted_email(self, mock_send_email):
    mock_send_email.return_value = True
    response = send_formatted_email(self.comment, to_email)
    mock_send_email.call_args_list
    ....
```

views.py

```
def send_formatted_email(comment, to_email):
    ...
    message = comment.comment
    subject = 'Comment posted'
    from_email = comment.user.email
    ...
    return send_email(subject, message, to_email, from_email)
```

util.py

```
def send_email(subject, message, to, from):
    return requests.post(
        ...
    )
```

I even tried `app.util.send_email = MagicMock(return_value=True)` but this didn't work either. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You patch where a function is *used*, not where it's *defined*. Try `@patch('app.views.send_email')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock a function defined in a separate Python module using mock's @patch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654009/how-to-mock-a-function-defined-in-a-separate-python-module-using-mocks-patch)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you it worked.

Comment: In the light of your answer now i am able to patch where function is defined if i import module instead of function itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python mock patch doesn't work as expected for public method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987973/python-mock-patch-doesnt-work-as-expected-for-public-method)

Answer (score 4):

Like [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) already mentioned there is already an answer under [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14654076/2947505).

In my case I were not able to use one of the alternatives that are provided (reload or patching my own module).

But I now just importing the needed method right before usage:

```
def send_formatted_email(comment, to_email):
    ...
    message = comment.comment
    subject = 'Comment posted'
    from_email = comment.user.email
    ...
    from app.util import send_email
    return send_email(subject, message, to_email, from_email)
```

This will load the module method after you patched it.

Cons:

- The import is executed before each method call.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import app.util

...

return util.send_email(subject, message, to_email, from_email)
```

or:

```
@patch('app.views.send_email')

...

return send_email(subject, message, to_email, from_email)
```